# IOS8 keyboard event not executing properly

Tags: ios, scroll, keyboard

Hi I am developing one iphone application in which I am using few keyboard events but those are not working properly in IOS8 as working in previous IOS versions. So here is my problem. I have two text fields. I am listening for two events `(void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification *)notification` and `(void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification`. Inside these methods I am scrolling my content according to keyboard height. In previous IOS version it is working properly but in IOS8 it is causing problem. Whenever I select any text field it is triggering `keyboardWasShown` but whenever I select another text field then again it is triggering same event even though keyboard already shown. In previous versions it is triggering only once but for IOS 8 it is triggering twice. Here is my code

```
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications {

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
}

- (void)deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications {

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                              object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                              object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification {
[LogRecords showLog:@"keyboard shown ... "];
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone || (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad && UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])))
{
   //scroll content here according to height of keyboard ;
}
}

- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification *)notification
{
[LogRecords showLog:@"keyboard hide "];
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone || (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad && UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])))
{
//scroll content here according to height of keyboard ;
}
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong or it is problem with new version? Need Help. Thank you.

Comment: Any one got solution for this?

Comment: Are you using `UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive`? It seems like `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` is being fired twice when you dismiss the keyboard interactively: once when you lift your finger after dragging the keyboard downward, and a second time when the keyboard is finally off-screen.

You can verify this by logging the `userInfo` dictionary on the notification when it is received. I'm not sure if this is intended behavior by Apple, or a bug, but you can use the frame info in the dict to determine how to adjust your scroll view, or use Heroico's fix.

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing the same thing, only in iOS8.

I worked around the issue by adding a semaphore for the handling of the notification:

```
@implementation MyViewController

//workaround to iOS 8 bug where the keyboard notification is fired up twice
static BOOL flag;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    if (flag) {
        return;
    }
    flag = YES;

  //your code for handling keyboard display
}

- (void)ga_keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)note {
    if (!flag) {
        return;
    }
    flag = NO;

    // your code for handling keyboard hiding
}
@end
```